# Create bar graph-find the average mpg by the number of gears

Tags: r

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(gear, mpg) %>%
summarise(m = mean(mpg)) %>%                                 
ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = gear)) +
geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

I cannot figure out to create a bargraph with the average mpg by the number of gears

Comment: You are grouping by `gears` and `mpg`, which means you will calculate the mean mpg for each unique gears-mpg pair, not what you want to do. Also, for your plot, thing about what you want on each axis.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am just learning this and it is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you need?

**packages**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

### Average mpg (m) by the number of gears

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = m, x = gear)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

1. First, we get the mean of mpg by gear. To do that, you want to group by gear (just gear. You don't need to group by mpg as well).
2. Ungroup, so you have a unified dataset.
3. Now you want to plot the mean you created (m) by gear. You can which of them go where. In this case, I put  `gear` on the x-axis and the mean of mpg on the y-axis.
4. Given you have specific values for the mean, you don't have to count all the values. Just plot the specific value you have there. Thus, use `stat = "identity"` instead of `stat = "count"`

Now you can play with colors using `fill` argument in `aes` and change the titles and axis labels.

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In base R (i.e. without additional libraries) you might do

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, gear, mean)) |>
  barplot(xlab='gear', ylab='n', col=4, main='My plot')
```

[image]